# Unbiased estimate of standard error of sample by bootstrapping

Tags: bootstrap, standard-error, bias

I'm trying to compute the standard error for a statistic on a small sample. Currently, what I'm doing is bootstrapping using the following pseudocode:

```
bootstrap_iters = 100000
for i in range(bootstrap_iters):
    bootstrap = statistic(samples_with_replacement(my_sample, len(my_sample)))
    res.append(bootstrap)

return sample_stddev(res)
```

To sanity check this, I tried this using the mean as the statistic and compared the value of this to the following estimator for the SEM:

$$
\hat {\mathrm{SE}} = \frac {\hat \sigma} {\sqrt n} = \frac {1} {\sqrt n} \sqrt {\frac{\sum (x_i - \mu)^2}{n - 1}}
$$

Unfortunately, for small samples ($n < 100$), the bootstrap value would be consistently less than the above value. In fact, I found it actually ended up being far closer to a version of the SE computed using the biased sample standard deviation estimator:
$$
\frac {1} {\sqrt n} \sqrt {\frac{\sum (x_i - \mu)^2}{n}}
$$

For larger samples, the error becomes negligible. It seems like what's happening is that the bootstrap is providing a biased estimate of the standard error. I considered just multiplying the bootstrap value by $\sqrt {\frac{n}{n - 1}}$, which would obviously fix the problem for the mean, but my goal is to be able to use this for various more complex statistics and this feels way too ad hoc for me to be comfortable doing so. Is there any principled way to correct for this bias in the SE?

Comment: No, this is a fundamental property of the bootstrap. It essentially provides a plug-in estimate for any statistic, but if the plug-in estimate would be biased, so too will the bootstrap. You can use a double bootstrap to attempt to correct for the bias.